# How can I access routes that has Laravel Guard?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to create Laravel code with login by multi-table. I don't have any problem with login, but when I access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products` it shows `Unathenticated` :
[image]

How can I access route by whos currently logging in? here is my code :

*Thanks in advance

1. AccountController.php (Login Method)

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if(strtolower($request->grantType) === "user") {
            if(Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
                $user = Auth::guard('user')->user();
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
                $success['name'] =  $user->name;
                $success['guard'] =  $user;
                return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
            } 
            else{ 
                return $this->sendError('Unauthorized', ['error'=>'Invalid credentials'], 401);
            } 
        } else if (strtolower($request->grantType) === "student") {
            if(Auth::guard('student')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
                $user = Auth::guard('student')->user();
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
                $success['name'] =  $user->name;
                $success['guard'] =  $user;
                return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
            } 
            else{ 
                return $this->sendError('Unauthorized', ['error'=>'Invalid credentials'], 401);
            } 
        } else if (strtolower($request->grantType) === "teacher") {
            if(Auth::guard('teacher')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
                $user = Auth::guard('user')->user();
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
                $success['name'] =  $user->name;
                $success['guard'] =  $user;
                return $this->sendResponse($success, 'Teacher login successfully.');
            } 
            else{ 
                return $this->sendError('Unauthorized', ['error'=>'Invalid credentials'], 401);
            } 
        } else {
            return $this->sendError('Bad Request', ['error'=>'No enum constant '.$request->grantType], 400);
        }
    }
```

2. Route/api.php

```
Route::post('register', [AccountController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('login', [AccountController::class, 'login']);
     
Route::middleware('auth:student')->group( function () {
    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
});
```

3. config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'user',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],
        'teacher' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'teacher',
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'student',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: I suggest you use "middleware".

Comment: i create StudentMiddleware and testing to show `Auth::guard('student')->check()`. when I print in my controller the result is `true` but when I print in middleware the result is `false`